# Jquery to Restrict users for date selection

Tags: jquery

Ok i have a Date option with three fields i.e. Date, Month and Year.

I would like to restrict my users using Jquery so that they cannot select a date range more than 3 months and 3 years.

Below are my fields

```
<select class="day">
<option value="--"></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
.....
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>

<select class="month">
<option value="--"></option>
<option value="1">Jan</option>
<option value="2">Feb</option>
...
<option value="12">Dec</option>
</select>

<select class="year">
<option value="--"></option>
<option value="1900">1900</option>
<option value="1901">1901</option>
<option value="1902">1902</option>
....
<option value="2099">2099</option>
</select>
```

Comment: 3 years and 3 months compared to which date? The current dale? Why not using a date picker so you can forget about leap years, date validations and all that stuff?

Comment: Yes compared to current date, I dont have option of date picker

Comment: Why no? Having 3 selects is a restriction?

Comment: Pick your desired date picker and I’ll help you

Comment: The default html date picker? You cant do that using the default one :/

Comment: how about bootstrap date picker?

Comment: Link? There are many and many date pickers with that name my firend.

Comment: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a date picked instead of 3 different selects. This snippet uses [this version](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker) of bootstrap date picker.

To restrict the date picker to certain range of dates, the `endDate` ([more info about the option](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#enddate)) or the `startDate` ([more info about the option](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate)) option must be set (or both). Both options accepts a specific plugin date format:

- `+` meand a positive date, date in the future
- `-` meand a negative date, date in the past
- `10d` specifies a number od days, in this case 10
- `2m` specifies a number of months, in this case 2
- `1y` specifies a number of years, in this case 1

So, if you would need to restrict the initial date to 3 years and 3 months from now, you will set the `startDate` to `-3y -3m`.

Hope it helps.

```js
$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
  startDate: "-3y -3m", // 3 years and 3 months from now
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
        <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
        <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" />
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks but this restricts the user to only select date 3 years before, it doesn't allow to select any current date. I would like tie user to not not select any date range more than 3 years and 3 months but they can still select any date under 3 years and 3 months

Comment: @AdeelAhmad i dont get it then, In the working example, you can select any date from now, the past, and until +3 years and 3 months.

Comment: @muecus yes that works for that but I need it to not select any past date i.e. -3 years and -3 months not +3years and +3 months :)

Comment: @AdeelAhmad let me see if i got it, you need a date range, and restrict the minimum date to 3 years and 3 months in the past. Check it now.

Comment: new to stackoverflow how to do +1?

Comment: @AdeelAhmad by the green tick, it's a zero The upper arrow adds a +1, the bottom one removes one.